# What does C-53 signify?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel

In *Captain Marvel*, the Kree refer to Earth as planet C-53.

Does this number signify anything or is it a randomized number assigned to Earth?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In *Captain Marvel*, Kree have assigned C-53 to planet Earth. That's what they call it. To them, Earth is just another planet in the universe.

It seems to be a random number assigned to Earth. There is nothing special came up with this number yet. Neither from production team nor in a movie.

From [Refinery29](https://www.refinery29.com/en-us/2019/03/225973/captain-marvel-movie-review-brie-larson-origin-story),

> As the two fight off some stray Skrulls (led by a hilarious Ben Mendelsohn), Vers starts to realize that the key to her past lies on C-53 (that's the Kree name for Earth — we're not that special).

Unless someone from production clarifies it or comes up with an easter egg, there is no significance of this number.

Comment: I would laugh my head off if it turned out C-53 was the office vending machine number for the writers favourite chocolate bar...

Comment: @BladeWraith You may laugh, but someone else Snickers...

Comment: You know C-60 fullerene looks like football C-53 more like earth maybe

Comment: Well, look at the names NASA has come up with for all the exoplanets they've been discovering lately.  They're all just boring letters and numbers.  Now we can imagine that some of those might harbor life, even intelligent life, and they might even have a name for themselves, but we'd never know.  This is just kind of the same situation in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

C-53 is also an alias for a human gene protein that facilitates cell differentiation.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @Chenmunka - It's legit, but C-53 was discovered in 1992 and I spent more time than I should have trying to determine the first time C-53 was used in the comics.  I know Captain Marvel dates back to the late 60's, I was trying to figure out if it was used in the comics before it was assigned to that protein, which would have debunked his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I researched for fun how C-53 could have any substantial significance.

I came across [an article from sciencealert.com](https://www.sciencealert.com/for-the-first-time-ever-astronomers-detected-planets-outside-our-galaxy-this-year/amp) that says that so far 53 exoplanets exist in our Milky Way using a technique predicted by Einstein. In addition, Iodine is 53d on periodic table of elements. So that and my idea of the C standing for carbon are eliminated.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site and the kind of quality we expect from answers. This, in my opinion, doesn't really seem like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing we're the 53rd star system and the C stands for the third planet, with Mercury and Venus being A-53 and B-53 respectively.